# GWT Apps not running on IPhone pseudo browser (embedded browser)

Tags: ios, iphone, gwt, gxt, captivenetwork

I build a GWT apps that deployed on a tomcat server. My apps was intended to use as a login gateway for a captive portal solution. When a device connected to our wifi hotspot, user redirected to our GWT apps and will be prompted to login / register before they can use our wifi connection.

I do some test using Android device, everything going well, the GWT apps was showed in Android pseudo browser. But things get weird when we do some test with iOS device (like iPhone 6, etc.), the GWT apps was not showed in iOS pseudo browser. Whenever I tried to connect to the wifi hotspot and enable the auto login, the pseudo browser will appear inside Settings menu, and only display a white blank page.

[image]

Furthermore, I tried to put some window.alert inside my GWT apps, first in onModuleLoad, other was in some child module, and when I test it again, not a single alert was prompted. So I assume that even the onModuleLoad was not called. 
I have two questions for this problems :

1. What is this iOS pseudo browser called? I need this pseudo browser name / term to googling more information about this browser. Does this pseudo browser could be launch independently without need to connect to a captive portal?
2. Does anyone know a solution or workaround for my GWT apps to running in iOS pseudo browser?

Note : I use mvp4g and also gxt in my GWT apps.

---

**Update 1**

Pseudo browser is a browser that lauch by system, for example when we tried to connect to a captive portal wifi using iOS device, in settings menu, system will launch a native or internal webview that redirected to a login url. The screenshoot I post was an example of pseudo browser. So I using a real device and not an emulator. 
I probably know the root cause of this problem, but I can't find a workaround or solution for this problem. So it looks like my GXT Apps not working because in iOS pseudo browser the user agent was not recognized. I compare it when I tried to access my GXT Apps using safari browser from the same device, the user agent was correct. I attached the screenshots :

Pseudo Browser : 
[image]

iPhone Safari : 
[image]

I tried to override the gxt.user.agent in my gwt.xml file like this :

```
<property-provider name="gxt.user.agent">        
    <![CDATA[{
            var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
            if (ua.indexOf('edge/') != -1) return 'edge';
            if (ua.indexOf('chrome') != -1) return 'chrome';
            if (ua.indexOf('trident') != -1 || ua.indexOf('msie') != -1) {
                if ($doc.documentMode >= 11) return 'ie11';
                if ($doc.documentMode >= 10) return 'ie10';
                if ($doc.documentMode >= 9) return 'ie9';
                if ($doc.documentMode >= 8) return 'ie8';
                return 'ie10';
            }
            if (ua.indexOf('safari') != -1) {
                if (ua.indexOf('version/3') != -1) return 'safari3';
                if (ua.indexOf('version/3') != -1) return 'safari4';
                return 'safari5';
            }
            if (ua.indexOf('gecko') != -1) {
                if (ua.indexOf('rv:1.8') != -1) return 'gecko1_8';
                return 'gecko1_9';
            }
            if (ua.indexOf('adobeair') != -1) return 'air';
            return 'safari5';
     }]]>
</property-provider>
```

But still not working for me, please help me. Thanks and regards.

Comment: What is a psuedo browser, is this an emulator running the browser?

Comment: @Branflake2267 pseudo browser is a browser that lauch by system, for example when we tried to connect to a captive portal wifi using iOS device, in settings menu, system will launch a native or internal webview that redirected to a login url. The screenshoot I post was an example of pseudo browser.